# VHDL 33.3 Mhz clock generated from a 50 Mhz clock

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to generate a 33.3Mhz clock from a 50Mhz clock in VHDL? If so, how?
Many thanks
Danny

Adding to this... with making a PLL in Qsys whats the difference between the "rst" that is always included in the PLL and asynchronous "rst" that is selectable when configuring the PLL?

Comment: As a design exercise, or practically? Practically, just instantiate a DCM or PLL block programmed to do the job you need.

Comment: For a start, do an Internet search on the title "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=VHDL+33.3+Mhz+clock+generated+from+a+50+Mhz+clock&t=h&ia=qa" and you will find some useful hits [HERE](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=VHDL+33.3+Mhz+clock+generated+from+a+50+Mhz+clock&t=h&ia=qa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Like Brian said in his comment (actually could be answer) just instantiate a PLL module with 33.3MHz clk output.

**Note:** your 50MHz and 33.3MHz clocks will now be in different *clock domains*. So take special care when signals are crossing between them. I would start by googling *synchronizer* ;)

Comment: :) Thanks, I will.